# Why did Holden have to kick Naomi?

Tags: tv, the-expanse-2015

At near the end of Episode Four of *The Expanse*, the Cant crew are trying to escape the Donnager before it goes kablooey.

Naomi and Holden are the last ones left when the Donnager stops moving. There is no longer any gravity, and Naomi and Holden begin floating. Holden, thinking quickly, hooks his suit up to Naomi's and *kicks her*, as hard as he can. She flies away from him, and he activates his mag boots. Then he yanks her back down.

So what was that all about? Why not just push her down? Why not just hook her up to you?

Comment: I don't watch this, but you might be interested in [conservation of momentum](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/ConservationofMomentum.html).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> For every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction.
>
> —Newton.

By kicking Naomi away, Holden propels himself down, so his activated magnetic boots can make contact with the floor. Once he's safe, he can reel her back in.

Had Holden been in the right position, he could've done it in reverse, pushing *Naomi* down, but he didn't know if she would've activated her boots in time. This way, he didn't need to depend on her, he just needed her mass.

Comment: -1, not complete unless you link forces to change in momentum :D

Comment: I hadn't even thought of that! The Expanse continues to surprise me with its complexity and realism.

Comment: Up until the (spoilers) and despite the mcguffin.... the expanse is *mostly* hard sci fi physics, both in terms of the book and the series